# Responsive/scaling div with image aligned to edges

Tags: css, image, html-table, alignment

I'm working on a site feature that I set up as a table. It contains text and an image. It needs to be responsive as well. I'd like the have the image on the right side of the table, with no space on the top, bottom, and right. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Goal of image bleed on top, bottom, and right]

And here is what I have built (a different image is being used):

[image: Current build with space between image and table]

And here is my code (HTML & CSS must be combined for use in Salesforce Marketing Cloud):

```
  <style>
    
    #content{
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size:14px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    #table{
      background-color: #fff;  
      border-radius: 12px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
      box-shadow: #63666A 1px 1px 1px 1px; 
      border-radius: 12px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
      color: black;
    }

    #title{
      font-size:20px; 
      font-weight:bold;
      color:#005da6; 
      padding-left:20px; 
      margin-top:5%;
    }
    
    #button{
      margin-left:20px; 
      padding:12px; 
      color:white; 
      background-color:#003150;
      width:35%;
      font-weight:bold;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-top: 10%;
      text-align:center;
    }
    
      #button a{
      color:white; 
      text-decoration: none;  
    }
    
      #button a:hover{
      color:#47a23f;
      text-decoration: none; 
    }
    
      #button a:active{
      color:#47a23f; 
      text-decoration: none; 
    }
    
      #button a:visited{
      color:white; 
      text-decoration: none; 
    }
    


    #img{
      max-width:100%;
      }
    
    .p {
      max-width:250px;
      font-weight: regular;
    }
    
  </style>
  
   <div id="content">
    <table id="table" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th><p id="title">Monthly tips <br> for well-being</p>
          <p style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px; font-weight:normal;" class="p">Check out our monthly newsletter for healthy living tips.</p>
      
    <p id="button"><a target="blank" href="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/5f6d1181-8af5-4000-a9ba-8b1789b29f58.pdf">See Tips</a></p>
        </th>
        <th><a target="blank" href="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/5f6d1181-8af5-4000-a9ba-8b1789b29f58.pdf"><img id="img" src="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/9388b441-bf80-4e2d-bc8a-34e827fb2eb6.png" alt="Tips for well-being"></a></th> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way to eliminate the extra space while still containing the image in the table & div?

Comment: The first thing is "don't use tables for layout"....it not the 1990's any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any padding and margin from the row and the 2nd header cell and also use border-collapse to get rid of the last little bit.

```html
<style>
  #content {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  #table {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: #63666A 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #005da6;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  
  #button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #003150;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #button a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #button a:hover {
    color: #47a23f;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #button a:active {
    color: #47a23f;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #button a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .p {
    max-width: 250px;
    font-weight: regular;
  }
  
  th:nth-child(2),
  tr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>

<div id="content">
  <table id="table" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p id="title">Monthly tips <br> for well-being</p>
        <p style="padding: 0 20px 0 20px; font-weight:normal;" class="p">Check out our monthly newsletter for healthy living tips.</p>

        <p id="button"><a target="blank" href="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/5f6d1181-8af5-4000-a9ba-8b1789b29f58.pdf">See Tips</a></p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a target="blank" href="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/5f6d1181-8af5-4000-a9ba-8b1789b29f58.pdf"><img id="img" src="https://image.e.activehealth.com/lib/fe3715707564077a711273/m/1/9388b441-bf80-4e2d-bc8a-34e827fb2eb6.png" alt="Tips for well-being"></a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, unless your data really is a table, and it looks more like a layout thing, then look into flex or grid as ways of laying things out now. Most browsers in use nowadays support them. You can check that out at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)